# call a controller method without passing requestparams to it

Tags: spring, spring-boot, pagination, spring-hateoas

I have an GET method to get all paginated songs from repository. I try to use HATEOAS and I'm trying to create a link to all songs, but when I need to call the controller method to get all songs, I need to pass page and size parameters but I don't what to pass them because I want all songs.

How to call a controller method which takes 2 @RequestParam without passing those params? Is this possible?

```
    @GetMapping("/songs/")
    public CollectionModel<EntityModel<SongAlbumDTO>> getAllSongs(
            @RequestParam(name = "page", required = false) Integer page,
            @RequestParam(name = "size",required = false) Integer size
    ) {
        if (page != null && size != null) {
            List<SongAlbumDTO> dtoSongList =  songService.findPaginatedSong(page,size).stream()
                    .map(SongAlbumAdapter::toSongAlbumDTO)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            List<EntityModel<SongAlbumDTO>> songs = dtoSongList.stream()
                    .map(songAlbum -> EntityModel.of(songAlbum,
                            linkTo(methodOn(SongAlbumController.class).getSongById(songAlbum.getId())).withSelfRel(),
                            linkTo(methodOn(SongAlbumController.class).getAllSongs(null,null)) // HERE, what to pass to function to get .../songs/ in response ?
                                    .withRel("songs"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
            return CollectionModel.of(songs,
                    linkTo(methodOn(SongAlbumController.class).getAllSongs(null, null)).withSelfRel()); // HERE, what to pass to function to get .../songs/ in response ?
        }
        else {
            List<SongAlbumDTO> list = songService.getAllSongs().stream()
                    .map(SongAlbumAdapter::toSongAlbumDTO)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            List<EntityModel<SongAlbumDTO>> songs = list.stream()
                    .map(songAlbum -> EntityModel.of(songAlbum,
                            linkTo(methodOn(SongAlbumController.class).getSongById(songAlbum.getId())).withSelfRel(),
                            linkTo(methodOn(SongAlbumController.class).getAllSongs(null, null)).withRel("songs"))).collect(Collectors.toList()); // HERE, what to pass to function to get .../songs/ in response ?
            return CollectionModel.of(songs,
                    linkTo(methodOn(SongAlbumController.class).getAllSongs(null,null)).withSelfRel()); // HERE, what to pass to function to get .../songs/ in response ?
        }

    }
```

If I made a request for songs, I get the response like

```
"_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/songcollection/songs/1/"
                    },
                    "songs": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/songcollection/songs/{?page,size}",
                        "templated": true
                    }
                }
```

For songs link, I want to path to be

```
http://localhost:8080/api/songcollection/songs
```

not

```
http://localhost:8080/api/songcollection/songs/{?page,size}
```

Comment: I think all you missing is a slash at the end of your URL `http://localhost:8080/api/songcollection/songs/`

Comment: This does not fix my problem. I want to get rid of (?page,size) from url

Comment: have you tried what I suggested? because you define page and size with `required = false` so you don't have to include those params when calling the API. look at your `@GetMapping("/songs/")` there is a slash at the end of your URL, so if you call the URL `.../songs` it won't get to your function, but `.../songs/` do.

Comment: My problem is not about calling the API, I call the api with .../songs/ and I get the songs. For each song I get link to the song itself .../song/id and I should have a link to all songs. Here is the problem, the url to all songs is not ok. I should have .../songs/ not .../songs/{?page,size}

Comment: I think I kinda know what you want, you want the `{?page, size}` disappears in the response part up there right? If so I don't think it can be done because those seem like it being generated, not something you can write off because those parameters are a part of the API you defined

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'm trying to make another GET for songs, to have 2 methods with same url pattern.

Comment: then I don't think it is doable, actually, there is a cheat around this, you can set up two functions to have the same URL but with a different method. if you're not too strict on those method patterns you can try that

Comment: but is there anything wrong with the above function of yours? with that function, you sort of has two different APIs for songs, one with params and one without.

Comment: I solved the problem. I made another method without params which gives me all songs and I kept the same url pattern /songs/. This method I called function from my post. I also changed the function from my post like '''@GetMapping(path = "/songs/", params = {"page", "size"})''' to avoid ambigous mapping.

Answer (score 0):

According to [odrotbohm](https://github.com/odrotbohm) from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/535#issuecomment-272863348 you can do that by expanding the link:

> Just expand the Link without handing any parameters into the method and you should get a plain URI in turn.